# Which will perform better in where Clause an IN or combination of OR in DB2

Tags: performance, db2, conditional-statements

Approach-1:
Select * from *Table* 
where col1 in ('A','B','C')
and col2='Something' 
Approach-2:
Select * from *Table* 
where (col1='A' or col1='B' or col1='C' ) 
and col2='Something'

Which approach is better here . Considering the query  will run for 50K in Zlinux db2 10.5.

Comment: What does the EXPLAIN result look like for both on your data? Indexes? Selectivity? ...?

Comment: How to check that EXPLAIN@ henrik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should *always* give your Db2-platform (z/os, i-series, linux/unix/windows) and Db2-version when asking for help because these can influence the answer(s).

You may find that the Db2-optimizer will automatically rewrite Approach-2 into Approach-1 , depending on your configuration - meaning the same access plan would then be used for both statements. You can prove this via studying the access plans for both statements, query rewrites are shown clearly.

To see the explain-plan, learn how to use tools [db2expln](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0005736.html), [db2exfmt](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0002353.html) (best) and '[explain plan](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000952.html) for SELECT ...'.

Some GUI tools have built-in support to let you see the access plans , for example IBM Data Studio  and DB-Visualizer among others.

The rewriting of queries into semantically equivalent and easier-to-optimize statements is described in the [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.perf.doc/doc/c0005293.html).